# unable to connect mongo on cloud using java

Tags: java, mongodb, cloud, jelastic

I deployed my java web application on jelastic.I created a node for glassfish and mongodb on jelastic.I am not able to connect to the database deployed on code.

I used the following way to connect to the database-

```
 Mongo mongo = new Mongo("http://arpitsolanki.jelastic.servint.net/", 27017);
```

but it throws a Number Format Exception

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "//arpitsolanki.jelastic.servint.net/"
```

What is the right way of connecting with the database?

Comment: do you tried `Mongo mongo = new Mongo("arpitsolanki.jelastic.servint.net");` ?

Comment: I did and it throws the same exception

Comment: Normal wise it's the correct way to connect MongoDB. Be sure that your base is up

Comment: This is not related to your question but couple of weeks ago new version of mongodb is released. Mongo class is deprecated. I would suggest using the MongoClient class instead.

Comment: yeah i had been using the older library till now.Just saw that new library has MongoClient class

Answer (score 0):

I have used Mongo Client for connection and it works fine for me

```
// import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
// import com.mongodb.DBObject;

   MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("URL", PORT);
   DB db = mongoClient.getDB("dbName");
   boolean auth = db.authenticate("username", password.toCharArray());
```